# jquery tableexport plugin: exclude divs?

Tags: jquery, excel

i am using the [tableexport plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tableexport.jquery.plugin) to export a table to excel. It works great. But i like to exclude so classes for example.

This is my table:

```
<table id="tabid">
<tr><td><div class="left"><strong>Name</strong></div><div class="image"><img src ....></div></td><td>1246223</td></tr>
</table>
```

I like to exclude the class image from exporting.

This is my script

```
function export_xls(){
                    $('#tabid').tableExport({type:'excel',".$ign."fileName: 'report',htmlContent: true, exportHiddenCells:true});
                }
```

If i disable html content then the text will not be printed in bold for example. So this is no option.

I did not find any exclude option. Maybe some of you can help.

If there is no solution. Do you have another plugin that works? (Export to excel with css)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from a cloned element before calling the `tableExport` function.

Using [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and then [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the element to [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
function export_xls(){

  // Clone the element to export
  let clone = $('#tabid').clone()

  // Remove what you want to remove from it
  clone.find("div.image").remove()

  // Append to body... out of view
  let temp = $("<div style='position: absolute;top:-10000px;'>").append(clone)
  $("body").append(temp)

  // Export
  clone.tableExport({...});

  // Remove the temp div after a delay...
  setTimeout(function(){
    temp.remove()
  },2000)
}
```

Comment: the excel file is empty: function export_xls(){

  // Clone the element to export
  let clone = $('#tabid').clone()

 
  // Export
  clone.tableExport({...});
}

Comment: Did you use the `tableExport` options that you had before  or `{...}`?? - It was just to shorten my answer...

Comment: Yes i used this:  clone.tableExport({type:'excel',".$ign."fileName: 'report',htmlContent: true, exportHiddenCells:true}); There is no error in the console. The excel file will open but it is empty.

Comment: Maybe the `clone` had to be appended temporarily for the plugin to work... I will edit something to try.